# Unable to iterate over Arc Mutex

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust

Consider the following code, I append each of my threads to a Vector in order to join them up to the main thread after I have spawned each thread, however I am not able to call `iter()` on my vector of JoinHandlers.

How can I go about doing this?

```
fn main() {
    let requests = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));
    let threads = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));

    for _x in 0..100 {
        println!("Spawning thread: {}", _x);

        let mut client = Client::new();
        let thread_items = requests.clone();

        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            for _y in 0..100 {
                println!("Firing requests: {}", _y);

                let start = time::precise_time_s();

                let _res = client.get("http://jacob.uk.com")
                    .header(Connection::close()) 
                    .send().unwrap();

                let end = time::precise_time_s();

                thread_items.lock().unwrap().push((Request::new(end-start)));
            }
        });

        threads.lock().unwrap().push((handle));
    }

    // src/main.rs:53:22: 53:30 error: type `alloc::arc::Arc<std::sync::mutex::Mutex<collections::vec::Vec<std::thread::JoinHandle<()>>>>` does not implement any method in scope named `unwrap`
    for t in threads.iter(){
        println!("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your code is missing all explanations about which libraries you are using and contains information irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you don't need `threads` to be contained in `Arc` in `Mutex`. You can keep it just `Vec`:

```
let mut threads = Vec::new();
...
threads.push(handle);
```

This is so because you don't share `threads` between, well, threads. You only access it from the main thread.

Second, if for some reason you *do* need to keep it in `Arc` (e.g. if your example does not reflect the actual structure of your program which is more complex), then you need to lock the mutex to obtain a reference to the contained vector, just as you do when pushing:

```
for t in threads.lock().unwrap().iter() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I can't call `.iter()` after `unwrap()`.